# Retrieving tokens from OAuth2 authorize endpoint in angularjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, oauth-2.0, owin

I am trying to use IdentityServer with an Angularjs application. The Angularjs front end is meant to call the authorize endpoint when an unauthenticated user attempts to navigate to the root url of the application. The app.config has a resolve property which will generate a routeChangeError. This event triggers a redirect to the OAuth2 Authorization endpoint (IdentityServer in my case, running on Asp.Net MVC).

```
baseballApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/players', {
        resolve: {
            auth: function ($q, $rootScope) {                    
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                if ($rootScope.token) {
                    deferred.resolve();
                } else {
                    deferred.reject();
                }                    
                return deferred.promise;
            }
    },
    templateUrl: '/FrontEnd/Templates/PlayerList.html',
    controller: 'PlayerListController'        
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/players' });

var spinnerFunction = function (data, headersGetter) {
    if (data) {
        $('#spinner').show();
        return data;
    }
};

$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(spinnerFunction);
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');}]).run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'authenticationService', function ($rootScope, $location, authenticationService) {
//authenticationService.getBearerToken().then(function(data) {
//    $rootScope.token = data;
//});

debugger;

var generateRandomString = function() {
    return (Math.random().toString(16) + "000000000").substr(2, 8);
}

var nonce = generateRandomString();
var state = generateRandomString();
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function () {
   window.location = 'https://localhost:44301/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=baseballStats&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44300%2f&response_type=id_token+token&scope=openid+profile+roles+baseballStatsApi&nonce=' + nonce + '&state=' + state;
});}]);
```

As you can see I redirect to the authorize endpoint if I don't have a token. However, it's not clear to me how I can retrieve the tokens after I have signed in on the authorization endpoint.

I have specified a return url, and after sign in it does redirect to the application, but how would I set up my angular code to retrieve the token that is supposed to be generated on the Authorize endpoint and sent back to the application?

I have seen many examples of people using bearer token authentication for angular, but I have not seen anyone use the Authorize endpoint of an OAuth2 server with Angular. In MVC, there are many built in callbacks to retrieve the token. I am looking for some ideas on how to implement this in angular.

Could you please give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT

I have also tried to pass a hash navigation tag in the redirect uri, but get an "Error unknown client" from IdentityServer. Please see the code below

```
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function () {
   var returnUrl = encodeURIComponent('https://localhost:44300/#/players');
   window.location = 'https://localhost:44301/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=baseballStats&redirect_uri=' + returnUrl + '&response_type=id_token+token&scope=openid+profile+roles+baseballStatsApi&nonce=' + nonce + '&state=' + state;
});
```

Anybody know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you're using the implicit flow grant for your spa js app?

In that case, the identity server, after you've logged in, will send the access token back to a call back url of your spa app. Using that call back page you are able to capture to token in order to pass it along to your resource server within the authorization header as a bearer token.

Checkout this video from Brock Allen, very well explained:
https://vimeo.com/131636653

By the way, you should use the oidc-token-manager, written by Brock himself. It is very easy to use and it abstracts away all communication with the identity server. It's also available on bower so you can grab it from there.

Finally I would like to point you to my own spa angular app I've been working on lately: https://github.com/GeertHuls/SecuredApi.

It actually uses the token manager in order to obtain access tokens, auto-refresh them an expose them throughout the entire angular app.

Hope this will inspire you a little in order to integrate this with angular.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This looks very promising. I will get back to you as soon as I've had a chance to go through all the material you provided.

Comment: Sure, let me know when you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks again for providing this information. You github repo was helpful. Just one question: I tried specifying the redirect_uri for the authorize endpoint to include the hash #/players/ (like your #/cb) (see my edit above). I get an "error unknown client" when I redirect to IdentityServer. Any idea why?

Comment: That's because the identity server isn't configured correctly. Check the clients config:https://github.com/GeertHuls/SecuredApi/blob/master/SecuredApi/IdentityServer/Config/Clients.cs#L27. The redirect urls must match the url configured in the js tokenmanager. Even a forward slash too many or too few will result in "client unkown" error.

Comment: And here's the client side call back url configuration: https://github.com/GeertHuls/SecuredApi/blob/master/SecuredApi/SpaClient/app/common/tokenManager.js#L14

Comment: Second part you should check is the "AllowedScopes" part on identity server: https://github.com/GeertHuls/SecuredApi/blob/master/SecuredApi/IdentityServer/Config/Clients.cs#L38. If the client is requesting scopes, not listed there, you will get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I sidestepped around this issue by creating a custom ActionResult which would return a JSON response with a token when the user was already logged in via .NET Auth cookies, it's a bit hacky and looks like this;

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult GetToken()
    {
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 403;
            return Json(new {message = "Forbidden - user not logged in."}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        var claims = new ClaimsPrincipal(User).Claims.ToArray();
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Bearer");
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
        var token = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
        return Json(new { token }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```